# Vue JS time-slots-generator how to get value from object then display PM / AM

Tags: javascript, vue.js, date, datetime

I use the [time-slots-generator](https://www.npmjs.com/package/time-slots-generator) package, to display the time from 0:15 to 24:00, the problem is that this package does not provide the ability to display AM / PM and I will have to do it manually

To do this, I took some example code from StackOverflow, then changed it a little, and got the following result

```
  let hours = 23;
  let minutes = 32;
  let ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
  hours = hours % 12;
  hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
  minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0'+minutes : minutes;
  const strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
  console.log(strTime)
```

If you, for example, change the value of the hours to 17 and change the variable minute to 25, then you get 17:25 pm I think the logic of this function is clear to you, it checks the value and displays either AM or PM

Now I need to link this logic with my time generator, at the moment I am using a loop to display the time from 0:15 to 24:00 as I mentioned earlier, this loop looks like this

```
  data() {
    return {
      timeSlots: (ts.getTimeSlots([], true, "quarter")),
    }
  },

formatAMPM() {
  let val = Object.values(this.timeSlots);
    for (let prop in val) {
     console.log( val[prop]);
  }
}
```

With this loop, I get the following result

[image]

As you already understood, now I need to do so that the times are displayed either AM or PM, maybe you can offer a simpler solution to solve this problem I will be glad about every advice, you can see [this example in codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/inspiring-mountain-i3di0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could move that time formatting snippet into a function that could be called on each `timeSlots` value:

```js
export default {
  methods: {
    formatAMPM() {
      const formatTime = time => {
        const parts = time.split(':');
        let hours = Number(parts[0]);
        let minutes = Number(parts[1]);
        let ampm = hours >= 12 ? 'pm' : 'am';
        hours = hours % 12;
        hours = hours ? hours : 12; // the hour '0' should be '12'
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? '0' + minutes : minutes;
        const strTime = hours + ':' + minutes + ' ' + ampm;
        return strTime;
      };

      Object.entries(this.timeSlots).forEach(([key, time]) => {
        this.timeSlots[key] = formatTime(time);
      });
    },
  }
}
```

[demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/formatting-time-entries-2m5kq?file=/src/components/HelloWorld.vue:3803-4444)

Answer (score 2):

For dates, I recommend a more robust and flexible solution. Using [`date-fns' format`](https://date-fns.org/v2.21.1/docs/format).

You can find an example here: https://github.com/date-fns/date-fns/issues/946#issuecomment-452766765

But using something like `format(new Date(), "hh:mmaaaaa'm'")` should be good enough, and flexible on top of it. Also, unlike Momentjs, this lib is optimized and does the job well.